# wowza + live + ffmpeg + hls player, how to create the playlist.m3u8?

Tags: ffmpeg, wowza

I'm trying to setup a wowza live test server and then I can play hls from my mobile app. It do work without any problem for vod. I can play it in my app. I can also see the .m3p8 file if I enter this uri in the browser.
I tried to do the same in live mode (my goal is to test some streaming parameters for live streaming). I tried to use ffmpeg to create the live stream:

ffmpeg -re -i "myInputTestVideo.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -vb 150000 -g 60 -vprofile baseline -level 2.1 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000

I created a "source file" and connected it to the "Incoming Streams".
I can see in my application's Monitoring / Network tab that it do getting the data from ffmpeg.

My problem is how to get the playlist.m3p8 file so I can play it from inside my app (hls based)?

Again, for now I need a way to test playing with the streaming settings and in real live I'll have a real live streaming source.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly and since you said that it works for you with a VoD and its own m3u8 uri, you seem to not know how to construct an m3u8 uri for live sources referenced by a stream file (not source file as you incorrectly wrote).

Considering you named your stream file for example udp.stream (that's the file including the udp://127.0.0.1:10000 address), simply point your hls player application to

```
http://{yourwowzaserver}/{yourliveapp}/udp.stream/playlist.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could push it to Wowza as rtsp (much better than udp) and then stream it further on to where you want. To push it to Wowza you probably will need to setup a username and password (Server > Source authentication) and then the output stream from ffmpeg can look something like this: rtsp://{user}:{pass}@{yourwowzaserver}/{yourliveapp}/mystream.
In Wowza you will see mystream in Incomming streams. From there you can access it with the classic http(s)://wowzaip:wowzaport/{yourliveapp}/mystream/playlist.m3u8

Anyways, Wowza support both rtsp and udp so you could use directly. If you want transcoding, ffmpeg will be kinder to server resources than Wowza.

Answer (score 0):

Worked:
To change the output of ffmpeg to -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/my_app/my.stream.stream and use it as the input in wowza.